# How to merge lines using awk command so that there should be specific fields in a line

Tags: awk, sed, paste

I want to merge some rows in a file so that the lines should contain  22 fields seperated by ~.

Input file looks like this.

```
200269~7414~0027001~VALTD~OM3500~963~~~~716~423~2523~Y~UN~~2423~223~~~~A~200423
```

2269~744~2701~VALD~3500~93~~~~76~423~223~Y~
UN~~243~223~~~~A~200123
209~7414~7001~VALD~OM30~963~~~

~76~23~2523~Y~UN~~223~223~~~~A~123

and So on

First line looks fine. 2nd and 3rd line needs to be merged so that it becomes a line with 22 fields. 4th,5th and 6th line should be merged and so on.

Expected output:

```
200269~7414~0027001~VALTD~OM3500~963~~~~716~423~2523~Y~UN~~2423~223~~~~A~200423
```

2269~744~2701~VALD~3500~93~~~~76~423~223~Y~UN~~243~223~~~~A~200123
209~7414~7001~VALD~OM30~963~~~~76~23~2523~Y~UN~~223~223~~~~A~123

The file has 10 GB data but the code I wrote (used while loop) is taking too much time to execute . How to solve this problem using awk/sed command?

Code Used:

```
IFS=$'\n'
set -f

while read line
do
count_tild=`echo $line | grep -o '~' | wc -l`
if [ $count_tild == 21 ]
then
echo $line 
else
checkLine
fi
done < file.txt



function checkLine
{
current_line=$line
read line1
next_line=$line1
new_line=`echo "$current_line$next_line"`
count_tild_mod=`echo $new_line | grep -o '~' | wc -l`
if [ $count_tild_mod == 21 ]
then
echo "$new_line"
else
line=$new_line
checkLine
fi
}
```

Comment: `code I wrote(used while loop)` .. please add that code to question... you probably wrote a shell loop? if so, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice why it would be slow

Comment: Do we just need to append blank fields with `~` to pad it out to 22 columns? Please share your desired results from this 6 lines of sample as it's not super clear how this should look after being processed. I would agree that `awk` is the right way to go here :)

Comment: Input lines will starts with numbers and only thing common that I know is there are 22 fields in every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="~" }
{
    sub(/^[0-9]+\./,"")
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"")

    $0 = prev $0
    if ( NF == 22 ) {
        print ++cnt "." $0
        prev = ""
    }
    else {
        prev = $0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1.200269~7414~0027001~VALTD~OM3500~963~~~~716~423~2523~Y~UN~~2423~223~~~~A~200423
2.2269~744~2701~VALD~3500~93~~~~76~423~223~Y~UN~~243~223~~~~A~200123
3.209~7414~7001~VALD~OM30~963~~~~76~23~2523~Y~UN~~223~223~~~~A~123
```

The assumption above is that you never have more than 22 fields on 1 line nor do you exceed 22 in any concatenation of the contiguous lines that are each less than 22 fields, just like you show in your sample input.

Comment: Thanks Morton.... I have edited the input and output results in the question as suggested by you. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks a lot Morton. It worked perfectly as I modified your code to my requirement. Please suggest if anything wrong below as per my requirement

tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="~" }
{
    $0 = prev $0
    if ( NF == 22 ) {
        print $0
        prev = "\n"
    }
    else {
        prev = $0
    }
}

Comment: What was wrong with the code exactly as I wrote it? It produces the output you said you wanted from the input you posted,

Comment: I was wrong here Morton... I have tested with the correct input file it looks perfect now for the above script

Comment: Hi Morton
Could you please explain the flow of execution here... I'm little confused here

Comment: If the current line has fewer than 22 fields it gets saved to a variable `prev`. When the next line is read it gets the value of `prev` prepended to it and then tested for 22 fields. If it now has 22 fields it gets printed and prev is set to null, otherwise see the first sentence again.

Comment: Thanks... This script saves lots of time for running huge file

Answer (score 1):

Using only the shell for this is slow, error-prone, and frustrating. Try Awk instead.

```
awk -F '~' 'NF==1 { next } # Hack; see below
     NF<22 {
         for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) f[++a]=$i }
    a==22 {
         for(i=1; i<=a; ++i) printf "%s%s", f[i], (i==22 ? "\n" : "~")
         a=0 }
    NF==22
    END {
         if(a) for(i=1; i<=a; i++) printf "%s%s", f[i], (i==a ? "\n" : "~") }' file.txt>file.new
```

This assumes that consecutive lines with too few fields will always add up to exactly 22 when you merge them. You might want to check this assumption (or perhaps accept this answer and ask a new question with more and better details). Or maybe just add something like

```
a>22 {
    print FILENAME ":" FNR ": Too many fields " a >"/dev/stderr"
    exit 1 }
```

The `NF==1` block is a hack to bypass the weirdness of the completely empty line 5 in your sample.

Your attempt contained multiple errors and inefficiencies; for a start, try http://shellcheck.net/ to diagnose many of them.

Comment: The resulting data format still sucks. Perhaps look into using a standard format; if CSV or TSV is not acceptable, perhaps JSON would work?

Comment: When I tried with this code for above sample data, I could see only the first line is getting displayed.
200269~7414~0027001~VALTD~OM3500~963~~~~716~423~2523~Y~UN~~2423~223~~~~A~200423

Comment: Then probably the stated assumption is false. There is a bug if the last line is incomplete, though; I'll post an update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But unfortunately still I'm not getting the expected result.
Now the output is as follows. First line displayed properly but the second line contains the rest of the line and putting extra '~'. Actually the requirement is no ~ symbol should be added to the output file. 

First Line: 200269~7414~0027001~VALTD~OM3500~963~~~~716~423~2523~Y~UN~~2423~223~~~~A~200423

Second Line:
2269~744~2701~VALD~3500~93~~~~76~423~223~Y~~UN~~243~223~~~~A~200123~209~7414~7001~VALD~OM30~963~~~
~~~76~23~2523~Y~UN~~223~223~~~~A~123

Comment: FYI `print | "cat>&2"` is more robust and portable than `print > "/dev/stderr"`.

Comment: I'm guessing the completely empty line 5 is throwing off both mine and the competing answer. See (slightly speculative) update now

Answer (score -1):

You can try this awk

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="~"
  }
  {
    while(NF<22) {
      if(NF==0)
        break
      a=$0
      getline
      $0=a$0
    }
    if(NF!=0)
      print
  }
' infile
```

or this sed

```
sed -E '
  :A
    s/((.*~){21})([^~]*)/\1\3/
    tB
    N
    bA
  :B
    s/\n//g
' infile
```

Comment: I'm not getting the proper result when I run this.
Only the 3rd line and 6th line are getting displayed.

Output:

UN~~243~223~~~~A~200123
~76~23~2523~Y~UN~~223~223~~~~A~123

Please help me to in getting the proper result as mentioned in the question